# Selection of Objects with composite(embedded) property based on their Manhattan distance

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Consider the following object classes:

```
+---------------------------+        +----------------------+
|Planet()                   |        |Coordinate()          |
+---------------------------+        +----------------------+
|coordinates   Coordinate() |        |xcoordinate       int |
|lastVisit              int |        |ycoordinate       int |
+---------------------------+        +----------------------+
```

I want to get those planets that are within z units distance from another planet, but only those with the highest lastVisit number, so that I get only the most recent planet info (it is possible that the same planet is saved multiple times, at different "lastVisit"s .

The Coordinate() object is annotated with `@Embeddable` and is `@embedded` within the planet object.

In my DAO, I have this method, that does *almost* what I want - I can extract only the latest instances of the planet:

```
@Override
public List<Planet> getRecentPlanets() {
    Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();

    // create a query and sort it by last name using sql
    Query<Planet> theQuery = session.createQuery("FROM Planet p WHERE (p.coordinates.xcoordinate, p.coordinates.ycoordinate, p.lastVisit) in"
            + "(SELECT p1.coordinates.xcoordinate, p1.coordinates.ycoordinate, max(p1.lastVisit) FROM Planet p1 group by p1.coordinates)",
                                                            Planet.class);

    return theQuery.getResultList();
}
```

However, I can't seem to grasp how I can include the Manhattan distance on the database side.

My questions are:

1. How can I achieve this selection on the database side using HQL?
2. Does this even make sense performance wise? Is it suitable to make the distance calculations in a java class?
3. How would I fare trying to use *hibernate criteria* (which I don't yet understand completely) to achieve the same in terms of Performance and Verbosity?
4. Would it make a difference to the answer if there was a larger grid and more visits per turn?

Additional Info: The database size is bounded by a sparse manhattan grid of roughly 500x500. I estimate that there are no more than 200 turns, where each turn roughly 50 "visits" can occur.